# Application messages

Tags: applications, notifications

Need assistance. If I power on or restart my GT-P7500 10.1 Samsung tablet, it takes an awe full long time to become usable. It keeps coming up with messages like "Messager is not responding" - with pop up to "close or report or wait choice". This carries on for a while with pop ups for various apps before it becomes stable and usable. Even then occasionally a pop up still appears.
I have cleared no of apps so that only half of the 32Gig Mem (stil got 11.7 Gig free). Running

Any help will be appreciated as this is very frustrating

Comment: First thing I'd try would be clearing all caches (which can be done by [booting into recovery mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) and select "wipe cache"). Sometimes "broken cache files" cause issues like that.

Comment: some unwanted applications will be restarting in the background causing to slow down..https://support.google.com/android-one/answer/4582729?hl=en